# How to calculate FLOPS(floating point operation per seconds) of a standard neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, opencl, benchmarking, mnist

I have just implemented a standard neural network for the MNIST dataset in C++ using OpenCL and ran it in Nvidia GPU. I have computed the normal training time and error calculation time. but I need to compute the FLOPS for the purpose of benchmarking.
can you please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to find out this?